# How to set spotify session expiration date?

Tags: ios, swift, session, spotify

So I build an application that allow user to stream spotify song, since we need to renew session whenever the session is expired I want to set the expiration date to "nil". With that my user session won't expired.

here is the code I want to use:

```
var jossession = SPTSession(userName: <#String!#>, accessToken: <#String!#>, expirationDate: <#NSDate!#>))
```

the problem is I don't know how to get current Username that just logged in to spotify.
How can I get the username?

Give me any advice, doesn't matter using obj-c or swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a request with the the access token which you get after login:

```
[SPTUser requestCurrentUserWithAccessToken:[[SPTAuth defaultInstance].session accessToken] callback:^(NSError *error, SPTUser* user)   
   NSLog(@"displayName : %@ , canonicalUserName: %@ , territoty: %@ , email: %@ , etc...", user.displayName, user.canonicalUserName, user.territory , user.emailAddress);
}];
```